# Vite escapes characters from index.html src tag

Tags: html, vite, index.html

I am trying to generate index.html with Vite that has unescaped variable in src tag, but Vite is always escaping it

What I want is this:

> ```
>   <!DOCTYPE html>
>   <html lang="en">
>     <head>
>        <script type="module" src="/{{ variable }}/assets/index.js"></script>
>     </head>
>     <body>
>     </body>
>   </html>
> ```

But after building with Vite it is transformed to

> ```
>   <!DOCTYPE html>
>   <html lang="en">
>     <head>
>        <script type="module" src="/%7B%7B%20variable%20%7D%7D/assets/index.js"></script>
>     </head>
>     <body>
>     </body>
>   </html>
> ```

I am trying to accomplish that by setting base property in Vite configuration as follows

> ```
> {
>    base: "/{{ variable }}"
> }
> ```

But obviously not working

Comment: vite does this to save us from possible "security threats".

Comment: agree but is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: I can think of a way using `Javascript` but that would be a workaround. Still a caveat it might have security concerns. Here you have to inject the `src` attribute and it's value

Answer (score 0):

I ended writing my own plugin, something like that:

```
plugins: [{
   name: "transform-index-html",
   transformIndexHtml(html) {
        return html.replaceAll("/value_to_replace", "{{ new value }}");
   },
}]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).